# Ruby: how to convert temperature units in a string?

Tags: ruby, regex, string

Is there an elegant regex-way with Ruby to replace all occurrences of °C to °F in a string (while at the same time converting the units)? For example:

> "Today it is 25°C and tomorrow 27 °C."

should result in something like:

> "Today it is 77°F and tomorrow 81 °F."

Comment: Why would one ever want to have weird units of measurements?

Comment: Don't ask me, ask the weird people ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# -*- encoding : utf-8 -*-
def c2f(c)
  c*9.0/5+32
end

def convert(string)
  string.gsub(/\d+\s?°C/){|s| "#{c2f(s[/\d+/].to_i)}°F"}
end

puts convert("Today it is 25°C and tomorrow 27 °C.")
# result is => Today it is 77.0°F and tomorrow 80.6°F.
```

Answer (score 1):

The block form of `String#gsub` looks to be what you need:

```
s = "Today it is 25C and tomorrow 27 C." # 
re = /(\d+\s?C)/ # allow a single space to be present, need to include the degree character
s.gsub(re) {|c| "%dF" % (c.to_f * 9.0 / 5.0 + 32.0).round } #=> "Today it is 77F and tomorrow 81F."
```

I've lost the degree character (I used Ruby 1.8.7, which isn't very Unicode-friendly) but hopefully this should be enough to see what might be possible.